# How can I access a controller variable inside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to access variable from `ng-repeat` inside controller, which is inside ng-repeat, code provided below. Unfortunately it won't work for me.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="r in results">
        <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
            <p>{{r.something}}</p>   ($parent.r.something won't work either)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The thing I need is to make ng-repeat within one controller, to make list of available desks (in parent controller I have searching, filters etc.) and then, when I click the button in chosen row of list (results), I need to take its (row's) parameters and do something with them INSIDE second (child?) controller.

Is it possible? And if possible - how to do it?

Comment: So why is the controller inside the repeat? Maybe you need a directive rather than a controller there.

Comment: Better use directives for things like, so you prevent bugs and a cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-repeat variable ($index) in the html and call a function on the controller

```
<div ng-repeat="r in results">
    <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
        <p>{{r.doSomething($index)}}</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat should be nested in the ng-controller if you want to access variables in ng-controller. Lets assume you have "results" defined as an object in SomeCtrl, you will be able to access it with an ng-repeat. Example:

In your controllers.js

```
appControllers.controller('SomeCtrl', function(){
      $scope.results = someData;
});
```

In your view,

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="r in results">
      <p>{{r.property}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to access it inside the controller , for traversing through the results inside controller

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the **controller as** syntax. 
See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CGMwPrL63z4b8nsZX2Ox?p=preview) for details.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent">
    <div ng-repeat="r in parent.results">
        <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl as child">
            <p>{{child.something(r)}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The recommended way to communicate across controller is via services. But in your case, I am not sure whether creating a cross cutting service would solve anything.. It would be something to think about though